# How to display most related content according to given keywords in a product area?

Tags: php, mysql, keyword-search

I am creating a product area.All of the products have some **keyword ids** in it.What i am going to implement is if a product was selected, i want to display **most related** other products beneath the page. As for example data,

### product_id | product_name | keywords

```
23     | product1     | 2,4,13
31     | product3     | 2,4,8
10     | product6     | 2,4
11     | product4     | 2,3
34     | product2     | 2,4
54     | product5     | 2,7
12     | product8     | 4,8
```

Lets say I have to display related products for product **contains keyword 2 and 4.**
Currently I am using following to get the related products

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE keywords REGEXP '(^|,)2(,|$)' OR keywords REGEXP '(^|,)4(,|$)' ORDER BY product_id"
```

But sometimes this will not return mostly related products.

As for the above example data, **product_id 23,31,10,34** should take higher precedence rather than other records.

Can that be possible? Then what should i do to overcome this? thanks for all replies.

Comment: You should have a separate `product_keywords` table which is one-to-many relationship with `products`.  Then you won't have to parse all that comma-separated stuff and you will be using the RDBMS for what it is intended for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a3937/11)

```
select t.*,
SIGN(FIND_IN_SET('2',keywords))+SIGN(FIND_IN_SET('4',keywords))
as FindWeight
from t
where 
SIGN(FIND_IN_SET('2',keywords))+SIGN(FIND_IN_SET('4',keywords))>0
ORDER BY FindWeight DESC
```

Comment: Thanks Friend. That make sense. I'll try and let you know.By the way quick note what should i do if i have only one keyword to search? thanks

Comment: In this case you should leave only one FIND_IN_SET. FIND_IN_SET output position in the set if the item doesn't exists in the set it outputs 0. So SUM of FIND_IN_SET results for all items you try to find shows we can say WEIGHT of KEYWORDS. For example if we find only 1 keyword then SUM will be less than if we find 2 keywords. And so on.

Comment: Thanks friend.It really works for more than 2 keywords.but not for single keyword.I will follow your advice and let you know.

Comment: I've changed query in my ANSWER now it works fine for more than 2 keywords. [And also here is an example for one keyword](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a3937/12)

Answer (score 0):

leftclickben is right about how you should have structured your tables.

However if you want to continue with this, then the following would work

```
keywords LIKE '2,%' OR keyword LIKE '%,2,%' OR keyword LIKE '%,4,%' OR keyword LIKE '%,4,%'
```

Careful - be very consistent about the placement of commas and spaces.